# REST Service calling from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, rest

Im developing a Rest Service in Python. Im calling it from vb.net like this:

```
Try
    Dim url As String = String.Format("http://localhost:5000/myapp/{0}", Code)
    Dim serviceRequest As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim response As String = serviceRequest.DownloadString(New Uri(url))
Catch ex As Exception
    Msgbox("Something is wrong")
Finally
    MsgboxEHN("Done")
End Try
```

This is working fine. Im testing from localhost and I call correctly the service and I know when it ends. 
Is it possible to control the service errors from visual?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can add a **TRY-CATCH STATEMENT** when executing

```
 process.start
```

to see if there are any errors while trying to start the process.Then you can follow [this](http://www.andreavb.com/tip020001.html)